# Parabolic Proof

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Prove that the foot of the perpendicular from the focus to any tangent of a parabola lies on the tangent to the vertex.

My issue with this problem is that I don't understand it completely. I've tried drawing it a few times, but I can't seem to form a precise image in my head of what it's depicting.
Here's my current understanding:

The "endpoint" of the perpendicular dropped from the focus to any arbitrary tangent of the parabola also somehow lies on the vertex. The tangent to the vertex of parabola, as I understand, can be described as the line $y = k$ or $x = h$ where $k$ is the ordinate point and $h$ is the abscissa.

If my above understanding is correct (which it 99.99% isn't), then I don't think the foot of the perpendicular from the focus to a tangent of a parabola can lie on the tangent to the vertex.

If anyone can provide a picture of the situation or give me a hint, that's more than enough for solving this problem. Thank you.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Intersection_of_a_tangent_and_perpendicular_from_focus for a diagram.